# gitlab - run pipeline for a non-master branch only

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

We are migrating away from Bitbucket to Gitlab and I have been tasked migrating the pipeline config over.

One thing I have been asked to look at is to configure the pipeline config file such that certain actions are only executed in a non-master branch.

For example in the master branch we want to do the following:

```
script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

But in any non-master branch we want to do the following:

```
script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - aws lambda update-function-code --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --function-name function1 --image-uri xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/function1:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

I am struggling to find any code examples that will achieve this, any ideas?

Comment: just a non master branch/default branch or only for merge requests?

Comment: Yeah any branch that is not the master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a rule like this:

```
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"' 

  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - aws lambda update-function-code --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --function-name function1 --image-uri xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/function1:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @tobie van der Merwe is correct and it will work. I just want to point out that you might want to do it a little bit different, to reduce duplication and to make the overview easier.

```yaml
docker-build:
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

push to aws:
  needs: ["docker-build"]
  script:
    - aws lambda update-function-code --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION --function-name function1 --image-uri xxxxxx.dkr.ecr.$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION.amazonaws.com/function1:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH != "master"'
```

This way you have the same functionality together, and just the different part separated in an own job. This reduces the maintaince effort as you have just one place where you need to change it.